# CoreGraphics drawing on a large UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a UIImage I draw lines on it that follow the users finger. It's like a drawing board. This works perfectly when the UIImage is small, say 500 x 600, but if it's like 1600 x 1200, it gets really scratchy and laggy. Is there a way I can optimize this? This is my drawing code in touchesModed:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
[drawImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 15.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//CGContextSetAlpha(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5f);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the entire 1600X1200 frame at a single go, why not draw it as it's needed. What I mean is since you are drawing the entire frame (which resides in memory) you are having patchy performance.

Try [**CATiledLayer**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). Basically you need to draw a screen size only which your device is capable of, anything more than that as the user scrolls you need to draw it on the fly.

This is what is used in Google Maps on iPad or iPhone. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new context and drawing the current image into it every time a touch moves, create a context using `CGBitmapContextCreate` and reuse that context. All previous drawing will already be in the context, and you won't have to create a new context each time a touch moves.

```
- (CGContextRef)drawingContext {
    if(!context) { // context is an instance variable of type CGContextRef
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        if(!colorSpace) return nil;
        context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, contextSize.width, contextSize.height,
                                        8, contextSize.width * 32, colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        if(!context) return nil;
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1,0,0,-1,0,contextSize.height));
        CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){CGPointZero,contextSize}, drawImageView.image.CGImage);
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 15.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    return context;
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGContextRef ctxt = [self drawingContext];
    CGContextBeginPath(ctxt);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctxt);
    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctxt);
    drawImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
    CGImageRelease(img);
}
```

This code requires the instance variables `CGContextRef context` and `CGSize contextSize`. The context will need to be released in dealloc, and whenever you change its size.